# Is it possible to replace Qt's Phonon with a more recent version?

Tags: qt, pyqt, phonon

I have some issues with Qt/Phonon that I think might be related to it being a bit outdated.

NokiaSoft doesn't care much about Qt for desktop, since the Phonon framework shipped with Qt has been untouched for several releases. No update from 4.6.x or 4.7.x has touched it, AFAICT.

So, have anyone attempted to recompile Qt/PyQt using a new(er) Phonon version, and are there any gotchas for this?

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest you can check out official phonon repos here:
https://projects.kde.org/projects/kdesupport/phonon

Comment: Well, yes. But does it easily replace the version in Qt 4.6/4.7?